# Disable search selection in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know if its possible to disable the search in "Selection" option when searching in Visual Studio?

I find the search selection really confusing and I never want to search in a selection. Ever! I often copy some code by selecting it first, and then I do a search for something to go and paste the code in, but Visual Studio then by default searches in the selected text, which is not what I want.

I'm interested in a solution that works in at least Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, but 2008 would also be nice.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It has (Finally!!!) been fixed with an option. Following the [vote](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4564453-provide-an-option-to-disable-search-selection) link from [acarlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746754/acarlon) :

> In Visual Studio 2015, you can prevent Visual Studio from
>   automatically switching to search in Selection scope by unchecking the
>   following tools-option:
>
> Tools-Options-Environment-Find and Replace-**Automatically limit search**
>   **to selection**

Great that the option is only on the *automation* . So in the (for me extremely rare) cases where the functionality could be handy it is still possible by explicitly selecting the scope "Selection"

ADD: As [Lexikos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894589/lexikos) points out in comment, the option of "Selection" is actually quite handy with "Replace", especially "Replace All"

Comment: I almost always want to limit search to the current selection (especially if it's multiple lines) when I'm using search-and-replace.  Thanks for pointing out the option, so that I could turn it on.

Comment: @Lexikos I so seldom use it, that I completely overlooked, that it could be really handy combined with "Replace ALL", I'll try to remember that, thanks.

Comment: Note, I have observed updates to Visual Studio resetting this option on me.

Comment: Thanks Elaskanator, yes got the same bug here.

Comment: Next step: a better default :)

Comment: Thanks, can't believe this is still the default option on vs2019 when it's not on vscode. Hopefully they changed it on vs2022

Answer (score 9):

There is no option currently, but you can vote for the option to disable it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4564453-provide-an-option-to-disable-search-selection)